# error while executing abc in yosys (win32)

Tags: yosys

I'm getting the following error while while using the command `abc -liberty cmos_cells.lib` (logical mapping). I was able to techmap, fsm map and memory map the veriog code. dfflibmap gets executed without any problem.

[image: error in command window]

[click for large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gemhy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me that ABC can't correctly parse the auto-generated `read_lib` command because of the spaces in `F:/FINAL YEAR POJECT/..`, try to specify the path to the cell library as absolute path, starting with `F:/FINALY~1/` instead of `F:/FINAL YEAR POJECT/..`, or simply rename that directory so it does not contain any whitespace in its name (or move Yosys to some other place).